# I can`t see sitemap.xml in django sitemap framework

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and i want to create sitemap of my suit. I use sitemap framework from django, but when i go to 127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml i have TemplateDoesNotExist error
This is my sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from datetime import datetime
from .models import *

class CharacterSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Character.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return datetime.now()

    def location(self, obj):
        return '/' + obj.server.link + '/' + obj.link
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .views import *
from core import api_views
from .models import *
from .sitemap import CharacterSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'character': CharacterSitemap,
}
urlpatterns = [
    **some urls**,
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

Where i must see my sitemap.xml document and what i am do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by sitemaps? What happens if you comment that out the sitemap and just hit  / or /admin or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. This is my error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /sitemap.xml

Comment: ok and did you follow this direction: `Make sure your TEMPLATES setting contains a DjangoTemplates backend whose APP_DIRS options is set to True. It’s in there by default, so you’ll only need to change this if you’ve changed that setting.`

Comment: Yes, i check it, all is good

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you add more Sites via Admin and delete some of them each site has an ID, it was not working for me once I changed the ID in the DB it started working, so make sure SITE_ID matches the ID in the database. That solved for me